# How to unpickle a Python instance that was saved before the class changed a member variable to a property?

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I have a class that used to have a field `data`, but later the class was changed and now `data` is a property.

I would like to be able to unpickle instances that were pickled before the change, to preserve backward compatibility. A minimal example for illustration (in Python 2, though it should be the same in Python 3):

```py
import pickle

class X(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 100

pickle.dump(X(), open("x-file",'w'))

# Redefine the class
class X(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = 101
    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data

y = pickle.load(open("x-file")) # cannot access the original data through y
print(y.data)
```

What I would like is to define a function `load` that unpickles the object, detects it is old style (e.g. by seeing that it doesn't have the `_data` field), and return a new style instance with its data instead. However, since the field `data` now is a property, the old `data` field was overwritten by the class definition.

Is there any easy way I can access the old data (i.e. other than parsing the pickle file myself, for example)?

**EDIT**
After Peter Wood's answer, I got to this solution:

```py
import pickle

class X(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 100

pickle.dump(X(), open("x-file",'w'))

# Redefine the class
class X(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = 101
    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        if not '_data' in state:
            self._data = state['data']
            del state['data']
        self.__dict__.update(state)

y = pickle.load(open("x-file")) # cannot access the original data through y
print(y.data)
```

Comment: You can define custom methods: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) says in [What can be pickled and unpickled?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled):

> If you plan to have long-lived objects that will see many versions of
> a class, it may be worthwhile to put a version number in the objects
> so that suitable conversions can be made by the class’s [**`__setstate__()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__)
> method.

This is one of four "magic" methods you can define on your classes to facilitate serialisation. See [Pickling Class Instances](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances).

Comment: Brilliant, this is *exactly* what I was looking for. I edited in a solution using `__setstate__()`.

Comment: @doetoe that's great, thanks for the feedback.